# Issue getting ads to show

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to get my Google ads to show on an Android app. I've done these things already:

- Connect to Firebase
- Added gradle file code
- Set up admob account
- Have the proper code

It seems like there's nothing more for me to do, but they're not showing up.

Here's an example of what I have in onCreate.

```
    //AdMob initialization
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "**myADmob ID**");

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
        }
    });
```

Here's a sample from my xml.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="banner_ad_unit_id_main"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="457dp">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to solve this from the info you gave. Basically what you've said is "I did everything right but it didn't work. Why didn't it work?" My guess is you don't actually have the proper code

Comment: I added my code @Ibenedetto

Answer (score 1):

Try this. As per Google Documentation,

> Note: If an app tries to load a banner that's too big for its layout,
>   the SDK won't display it. Instead, an error message will be written to
>   the log.

Make sure you are giving enough space for the ad to show up(which is 320x50 dp). You can try hard-code the value for testing.

Can you also check the log and check the internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml